# Is there a way that I can stop people from standing still too long?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a map where the player is not allowed to stand still in a certain radius of blocks (only sprint parkour, no stopping!) and if I search Google it comes up with how to create a AFK machine.

**Is there a way that I can stop people from standing still?**

Comment: Away from Keyboard sound the exact same as standing still. have you looked at how these AFK Machines work because if they are detecting no key presses in [X] ticks then you just need to modify it to limit to only movement key presses (ie. W, A, S,D) and a less of a delay (ie. you can't be not pressing a key for 1 tick)

Comment: I'm voting to close as off-topic because it's not about the game Minecraft itself but about developement of modifications.

Comment: @Nitro.de Making maps using powerful Command block system is not "development of modifications", it is exactly how the vanilla, unmodded game is supposed to be played. I see no reason why the question "how to do something in my map", tagged with "redstone" and "server" is about mod development, even if the answer will be "there is no way, you'll need to write your own mod".

Comment: I changed the title to be more specific to the problem, as originally it sounded like it was too broad. And @OrcJMR is correct, asking for help with Minecraft Commands is allowed here

Comment: @OrcJMR Thanks for the explanation, it's good to know that Minecraft Command questions are allowed, was the first minecraft question i've ever looked in^^

Comment: You say you want to "stop people from standing still". Does this mean you want them to be moved automatically without input, or killed if they stop moving, or teleported back to the start of the parkour, or do you just want to detect if someone is standing still, etc.?

Comment: Try having a scoreboard stat of distance walked that resets every tick

Answer (score 3):

Setup

```
/scoreboard objectives add walkDistance stat.walkOneCm
/scoreboard objectives add walking dummy
```

Clock

```
/scoreboard players set @a walking 0
/scoreboard players set @a[score_walkDistance_min=1] walking 1
/<command> @a[score_walking=0]
/scoreboard players set @a walkDistance 0
```

A walk distance is maintained and if the player does not move after the last execution of this command sequence, his walking score will not be set to 1 and the command will be executed on him.

Comment: The second objective is not needed. You can directly run the command on `@a[score_walkDistance=X]`. Also, I suggest making the clock slower and increasing the X, since walkDistance is not updated while the player is mid-jump, but will be updated with the distance jumped once he lands.